# aws custom event on schedult to trigger lambda Using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to create a custom event which  should be passed to  Lambda on a schedule
I was able to create a scheduled  event
But not able to pass custom event details:

so i want something like this

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "roup1-rule" {
  name                = "Group1"
  description         = "Group1"
  schedule_expression = "rate(10 minutes)"
  is_enabled          = true
  event_pattern       = <<EOF
{
  "source": ["Group1"],
  "groupNumber":["Group1"],
  "notificationDate":["-"]
}
EOF
}
```

But I only get empty event like this

```
{'version': '0', 'id': '8d41b334-297c-bc93-795d-54b7622a3da7', 'detail-type': 'Scheduled Event', 'source': 'aws.events', 'account': '215132885729', 'time': '2021-12-06T21:05:34Z', 'region': 'us-east-1', 'resources': ['arn:aws:events:us-east-1:215132885729:rule/gov-prov-srvcs-Demographic_Group1'], 'detail': {}}
{'version': '0', 'id': '8d41b334-297c-bc93-795d-54b7622a3da7', 'detail-type': 'Scheduled Event', 'source': 'aws.events', 'account': '215132885729', 'time': '2021-12-06T21:05:34Z', 'region': 'us-east-1', 'resources': ['arn:aws:events:us-east-1:215132885729:rule/gov-prov-srvcs-Demographic_Group1'], 'detail': {}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`event_pattern` is not used with `schedule_expression`. `event_pattern` is only used to filter out events generated by other services.

You have to add the `event` to your function's code. Its a constant value anyway.

Comment: cant we pass a constant json . i can do this via console to send constant json at a schedule. but unable to do this in TF

Comment: resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "Group1-tgt" {
  rule = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.Group1-rule.name
  arn  = aws_lambda_function.createtrigger.arn
    event_pattern       = <<EOF
{
  "source": ["Group1"],
  "groupNumber":["Group1"],
  "notificationDate":["-"]
}
EOF
}

Comment: @devx You have to use [input](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_event_target#input).